# Apache config api endpoint

Tags: apache, configuration

I am running a vue js application as a v-host (app.test.com) on
http://app.test.com
The backend is a go application (which implements a webserver on its own) and is running on
http://localhost:8000

Is it possible to configure apache to redirect/proxy all request that go to http://app.test.com/api to http://localhost:8000 ?
Let's say i call http://app.test.com/api/endpoint1 from the vue application i'd like it to be proxied to http://localhost:8000/api/endpoint1.

I normaly have a dedicated dns for the api and using this config then in the v-host:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
```

which works good. 
But i can't figure out how to use this in a allready defined v-host.

Any hints/examples?

Many thanks

Comment: what's the problem? can't you already access the go application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for this question. Managed to run this .. forgot to add the Proxy * directive to the config...

```
ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        <Proxy *>
              Order deny,allow
              Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass /api/ http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/
        ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/
```

does it all, if someone Needs this