# Apache running API on subdirectory prefix

Tags: apache, ubuntu, .net-6.0, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-22.04

Ubuntu 22.04 | Apache 2.4.52

I followed the steps on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I made it work so that the .NET Core Web API is running on http://127.0.0.1:5000.

My apache config currently looks like this in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}s
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName mydomain.test
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.test
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The config with the same name but with a suffix "-l-ssl" looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        ServerName mydomain.test
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api-access.log common
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.test/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.test/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

This is all working and I can call my api on my root example https://mydomain.test/ping

However I want my API to run on a subdirectory `/api` and my Node Nuxt 3 application to run on the  root. I did this with pm2 that is running on http://localhost:3000. If I change http://127.0.0.1:5000/ to http://localhost:3000 in the config, my Nuxt3 app will show up.

How do I do this? I am new to Apache and Ubuntu and I wish someone could help me with this troubles I am facing to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and I made it work like a charm with the following.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}s
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /api/ http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName mydomain.test
    
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.test
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks to [rene marxis post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904285/apache-config-api-endpoint)